# Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 - Wi-Fi hotspot not work in anyway

Tags: 16.04, wireless, gnome, broadcom, hot-spot

Wireless-script info: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24478582

I trying use so **many** ways to create hotspot, but nothing works ask for any information - i'll answer.

I want to create hotspot visible to android. I created that, but I can't connect to it. I am just lost among lots of ways to do it.

Starts from just create wifi, connect via network manager and use "connect to hide network", ending in terminal with many commands. I search for working instructions that will be suitable with my OS, drivers, wireless card, etc.

(and sorry for my English)

Help me please! Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] and: 1. Describe what you want to do and 2. What have you tried already. PS - This is not a forum and even in a forum you should never post things like is *I trying use so MANY ways to create hotspot, but nothing work*, you're supposed to explain what you ave tried already and the results, in order to avoid having people suggesting what you already tried.

Comment: Oh god, i did it! It's looks like lottery. I set an open-source driver, and turn on hotspot on native network manager.(before it not works) than i change that Hotspot connection via nm-connection-editor on WPA2 and save, and it works! Thank you guys, and sorry for duplicate.  I scoured the Internet and started to look for answer here in desperation.